# If React props are readonly, how they can change (whats the usage of getDerivedStateFromProps)?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React. I learned that props in react are readonly.

But i read somewhere:

> getDerivedStateFromProps updates the state based on prop changes

So i got confused. If props are readonly, how they can change?

Comment: Props are just an object ,so it can be mutable.You can edit props but it will change the original object.You can do that,but props are meant for readonly according to standard practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are readonly in the context of a component, meaning, you can't assign a new value to them.

But a parent that passes props to child, can pass different props based on some condition. In that case, the child get rendered with a different props.

Example:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 0,
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child prop1={this.state.value} />
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ value: this.state.value + 1 })}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In my example, each click on the parent's button will change it state, therefore, React will re-render it, and then this parent will pass a new value to Child component.

Comment: So Developer can't change props, but parent can (when parent's state changes, child props changes.). right?

Comment: Kinda, I've gave only one option of prop change in child, via parent state change.
There are more options, for example browsers events such as scroll position or window size

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Sorry becuse i'm new user and can't upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to understand component life-cycle and how to use and handle props which is described beautifully in below links:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only

Props are read only means you can't change the value, but it doesn't mean you can't update it, for that you need to pass updated props back to child component and go any lifecycle methods to it.

Answer (score 0):

An update can be caused by changes to props or state.
when there is update `render()` method is get called.
you are saying update to props, which directly means you are changing and modifying child,
props changed means, the data passed from parent is changed which leads in changing props,
always remember state passed from parent is considered as props for child is key point.
`static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)` gets called right after `render()` used rarely mailnly for animations transitions purposes.
the things possible with `componentWillRecieveProps()` and `componentDidUpdate()` is now done by `getDerivedStateFromProps()`, it will return object in response to change in props, and null if no change, sounds wonderful.
as you can see method is `static` you cant change any data, you can just play with your `nextProps` and `prevState` only.
this is useful for components having async api calls.